# If child doesn't have class add class

Tags: jquery, if-statement, addclass

I'm trying to add a class to a child via jquery only if all the children of the parent do not contain the class already. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

https://jsfiddle.net/54988qdb/

```
<style type="text/css">
.active-tag {
    color: red;
}
</style>

<div class="tagcloud">
  <a class="all" href="#all">All</a>
  <a class="test1" href="#1">1</a>
  <a class="test2" href="#1">1</a>
  <a class="test3" href="#1">1</a>
</div>

<script>
  if (!$('.tagcloud a').hasClass('active-tag')) {
    $('.all').addClass('active-tag');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle

Comment: It [works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/72nc412d/) when you include jQuery and put your script inside an onLoad block (though in your verbatim example that wouldn't be necessary).

Comment: Bwhahaha! Oh my. Thank you. Lol. I've been working on this problem (a larger one related to this) for three days. I think my brain is a bit fried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@j08691 answered the question. I forgot to define jquery in my jsfiddle (facepalm).

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify things by using the length of the jQuery selector:

```
if( ! $('.tagcloud .active-tag').length ) {
  $('.all').addClass('active-tag');
}
```

edit:

Your fiddle doesn't work because jQuery wasn't included.